# Javascript all buttons not getting clicked

Tags: javascript

Hello Developers I am facing with a problem in `JavaScript`, i make a button  to click and display a text, but only first button clicked, others do not get clicked,

How can i fix this ?

```js
 let btn = document.querySelector(".buy");
 btn.addEventListener("click", e=> {
      btn.innerHTML = "Albenis";

 })
```

```html
<button class="buy">Add<i class="las la-shopping-cart la-2x  "></i></button>
<button class="buy">Edit<i class="las la-shopping-cart la-2x  "></i></button>
<button class="buy">Update<i class="las la-shopping-cart la-2x  "></i></button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `querySelectorAll` along with `forEach` method to attach `eventListener` to your button and change the text of the clicked.

```
let getButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.buy') //get all buttons

getButtons.forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    btn.innerHTML = "Albenis"; //replace text
  })
})
```

**Demo:**

```js
let getButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.buy')

getButtons.forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    btn.innerHTML = "Albenis";
  })
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxst.icons8.com/vue-static/landings/line-awesome/line-awesome/1.3.0/css/line-awesome.min.css">
<button class="buy">Add<i class="las la-shopping-cart la-2x  "></i></button>
<button class="buy">Edit<i class="las la-shopping-cart la-2x  "></i></button>
<button class="buy">Update<i class="las la-shopping-cart la-2x  "></i></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

`querySelector` only give you the first element, you need to use `querySelectorAll` to get all elements in the same class, check the code below:

```
const myButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".buy");
    for (let i = 0; i < myButtons.length; i++) {
        myButtons[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            e.target.innerHTML = "Albenis";
        });
    }
```

Comment: it displays  an error , x is not defined, what to do ?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (app.js:4)   ? what to do bro?

Comment: sorry, this one is tested, check it now

Answer (score 1):

When you use `querySelector` it gets the first element only so you could use `qyerySelectorAll` that will return an `HTMLCollection` of elements but this will not be efficient enough because in this case you will add `listener` to each element in this collection so the most efficient way to do that adds these **buttons** in `div` and listen
to this element only instead of all buttons and run your logic in case of you clicked on of the button you want

in your case, all the button want have a class called `buy` so you will listen if a button
clicked inside the `div` with class of name `buy` run some code.

```js
 let buttonsContainer = document.getElementById("buttons");
 buttonsContainer.addEventListener("click", e => {
      let el = e.target; 
      if(el.tagName === 'BUTTON' && el.classList.contains('buy')){
        el.innerHTML = "Albenis";
      }
 })
```

```html
   <div id="buttons">
<button class="buy">Add<i class="las la-shopping-cart la-2x  "></i></button>
<button class="buy">Edit<i class="las la-shopping-cart la-2x  "></i></button>
<button class="buy">Update<i class="las la-shopping-cart la-2x  "></i></button>
   </div>
```